# Getting driving instructions in android application using Google Directions API

Tags: java, android, unicode, driving-directions

I have this android app where I am supposed to show the driving directions to the users.
I am using Google Directions API for this.
This involves making request to their url and getting the JSON in result.
Now, the problem is : the driving directions are inside the TAG/Name - "html-instructions".
Here I get the directions, but it's embedded with unicode characters for eg.

"html_instructions": "Take the 1st \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e toward \u003cb\u003eBannerugatta Rd\u003c/b\u003e"

How do I get rid of these unicode values and get the plain text out of it.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
try {
    // Convert from Unicode to UTF-8
    String string = "abc\u5639\u563b";
    byte[] utf8 = string.getBytes("UTF-8");

    // Convert from UTF-8 to Unicode
    string = new String(utf8, "UTF-8");

} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {}
```

Comment: thanks for answering. Actually in actual text that I got after parsing had HTML tags which I removed using  replaceAll("\\<.*?>","").  But Still thanks for concern

Comment: You answer didn't work for me. The `replaceAll("\\<.*?>","")` of @Ankit, yes.

Answer (score 0):

direcObject.getString("html_instructions").replaceAll("\<.*?>","") works for getting html instruction without tag